# change input form to textarea without affecting database

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made a complete website with 4 form inputs, the inputs are text inputs and it is connected to the MySQL database. Now I want to change one of those text inputs to a textbox and when I do that it doesn't send the data to the database anymore for the specific 'message' field.

```js
//php code to insert to db
 <?php

$errors         = array();   // array to hold validation errors
$data    = array();   // array to pass back data
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone_number'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

// validate the variables ======================================================
 // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to $errors array 

 if (empty($_POST['name']))
 {
  $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
 }

 if (empty($_POST['email']))
 {
  $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
 } else {
  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email))
  {
   $errors ['email']= '<b>The email you entered does not appear to be valid</b></br>';
  }
 }

 if (empty($_POST['phone_number'])){
  $errors['phone_number'] = 'Phone number is required.';
 } else{
  $phone_number_exp ='/^[0-9]{5,12}$/';
  if(!preg_match($phone_number_exp, $phone))
  {
     $errors ['phone_number']='<b>Phone number entered is invalid</b></br>';
  }                  
 }
 if (empty($_POST['message'])){
  $errors['message'] = 'Message is required.';
 }

// return a response ===========================================================

 // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
 if ( ! empty($errors)) {

  // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
  $data['success'] = false ;
  $data['errors']  = $errors ; 
 } else 
 {

  // success processing


//connecting to the db

$dbhost = 'localhost';  
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = '1';

$dbconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$query = ("INSERT INTO user (name, email, phone_number, message) VALUES ('$name','$email','$phone','$message')");
mysql_query($query); 
  
        {
    $data['1'] = false;
    }
// email sent from gmail client id = --- 
$email_to="---";
$email_subject="Lead Form"; 
$msg = "Form details from interested customer:\n\n";
 
  function clean($string)
  {
   $sickstring = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
   return str_replace($sickstring,"-",$string);
   //replaces any characters found in the array with a "-".
  } 
  $msg .= "Email: ".clean($email)."\n";
     $msg .= "Phone Number: ".clean($phone)."\n";
  $msg .= "Name: ".clean($name)."\n";
  $msg .= "Message: " . ($message)."\n";

   /* if using the name variable
  $message .= "name: ".clean($name)."\n"; */
  
  //header for email.. variable not working , check variable on thursday ..  
  
  $headers = "From: " . ($email) . "\r\n".
  "Reply_To: " . ($email) . "\r\n".
  "xmailer: php/" . phpversion();
  
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $msg, $headers);

  $data['success'] = true;
  $data['message'] = 'Success!'; 
 
 }// return all our data to an AJAX call
 echo json_encode($data);
```

```html
 <form action="process.php" method="POST" id="ezform">
    
        
        <!-- NAME -->
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            
        </div>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@etc.com">
            
        </div>

        <!-- NUMBER -->
        <div id="phone_number-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_number">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" placeholder="Number">
            
        </div>
        <!--MESSAGE-->
        <div id="message-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Your Message">
            
        </div>
         <div id="Demo-BS" style="padding:30px;">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: You're not escaping your data properly, and you're using an obsolete API. Newlines are going to be trouble in this arrangement.

Comment: Can you please add full php and html code. As I can see there is only one input and you are saying it's 4.

Comment: noted. will keep that in mind for future practices.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code above query You have written.

```
$message = htmlentities($message);
```

Although you are using text-area so you should use `htmlentities` to escaping the HTML characters